# How to show UITabBarController after a move from Nib-File

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to come back from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController`. `UITableViewController` is subview of `UITabBarController`. I wrote following code for it. But `UITabBarController` doesn't load. I searched and found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132074/unable-to-show-a-uitabbarcontroller-from-a-nib-file), but when I move by link I see **Page not found**. How it make programmatically? Please help me.

```
  @IBAction func backPlaylistTable(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if boolForSong == true {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
            let playlistTable = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("playlistNavi") as! UINavigationController
            presentViewController(playlistTable, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

`UITableViewController` has the following code

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

**UPDATE**
My `UITabBarController`. I updated it. I want to move from the third `UIViewController` to the third `UITableViewController`, but when I make it, `UITabBarController` doesn't load.

[image]

Still I tried it but when I move from `UIViewConroller`, UITabBarController open the first `UITabBarController` but I want `UITabBarController` opens the third `UITableViewController`

```
 @IBAction func thirdPlaylist(sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let passToTaBBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        let playListTVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("playlistTVCStoryboard") as! UITableViewController
        passToTaBBarController.selectedViewController?.presentViewController(playListTVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        presentViewController(passToTaBBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Do you have UITabBarController as rootViewController of your UINavigationController?

Comment: UITabBarController is rootViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I changed my code and it works for me. I made that `UITabBarController` will select `UITableViewController` by index.

```
  @IBAction func thirdPlaylist(sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let passToTaBBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        passToTaBBarController.selectedIndex = 2
        presentViewController(passToTaBBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the UITabBarController
change the code like this:

```
@IBAction func backPlaylistTable(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if boolForSong == true {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let tabCro = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("you tab cro id") as! UITabBarController
        presentViewController(tabCro, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: UITabBarController has three UITableViewController. And I want to load the third controller but UITabBarController doesn't load

Comment: you make sure your tabbarController has three table?

Comment: Check the tabbarController.viewControllers.   If it's count == 1, you need check you tabBarController.

Comment: yes, please look at my question. I updated it. I want to move from the third UIViewController to the third UITableViewController, but when I make it, UITabBarController doesn't load.

Comment: let passToTaBBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController;
passToTaBBarController..selectedIndex = 2;
presentViewController(passToTaBBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)